# Find the last occurrence of a word in a large file with python

Tags: python, text

I have a very large text file. I want to search for the last occurrence of a specific word and then perform certain operations on the lines that follows it.

I can do something like:

```
if "word" in line.split():
    do something
```

I am only interested in the last occurrence of `"word"` however.

Comment: Depending on the file size, you may want to start at the end and read in chunks, seeking backward.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind google is your friend

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @Bonifacio2: about 300k lines.

Comment: use .rfind('word') operator

Answer (score 8):

Well an easier and quicker solution would be to open the file in reversed order and then searching the first word location.

In python 2.6 you can do something like (where word is string you are looking for)

```
for line in reversed(open("filename").readlines()):
    if word in line:
    # Do the operations here when you find the line
```

Answer (score 5):

If the file is hundreds of megabytes or even gigabytes in size, then you may want to use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/mmap.html) so you don't have to read the entire file into memory.  The [rfind](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/mmap.html?highlight=mmap.rfind#mmap.rfind) method finds the last occurrence of a string in the file.

```
import mmap

with open('large_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)  
                          # prot argument is *nix only

    i = m.rfind('word')   # search for last occurrence of 'word'
    m.seek(i)             # seek to the location
    line = m.readline()   # read to the end of the line
    print line
    nextline = m.readline()
```

Just keep calling `readline()` to read following lines.

If the file is extremely large (like tens of gigabytes) then you can map it in chunks with the *length* and *offset* arguments of `mmap()`

Comment: I just tried this and the number return by m.rfind(word.encode()) does not appear to be a line number but perhaps the byte position in the file?

Comment: Yes that’s correct, rfind() will return the byte position in the file, not the line number.

Comment: The OP didn’t ask for the line number, they just wanted to process the lines following the last match.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read()
answer = lines.find('word')
```

and then you can pick the last word from this

You may also use **[str.rfind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind)**

```
str.rfind(sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Return the highest index in the string where substring sub is found,
>   such that sub is contained within s[start:end]. Optional arguments
>   start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 on
>   failure.

Comment: This isn't quit the same as what the OP does.  Compare `"name" in "protect your enamel".split()` with `"protect your enamel".rfind("name")`.

Comment: @user3414693: about 300k lines.

Comment: @hat:- Yes it will so you dont want to read it entirely in memory and yes you have to read it sequentially

Answer (score 2):

You can open your file, transform it into a list, reverse its order and iterate looking for your word.

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file_:
    line_list = list(file_)
    line_list.reverse()

    for line in line_list:
        if line.find('word') != -1:
            # do something
            print line
```

Optionally you can specify the size of the file buffer passing the buffer size (in bytes) as the third parameter of `open`. For instance: `with open('file.txt','r', 1024) as file_:`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is too large to be open in memory, and the word you are looking for is more likely to be found in the second part of your file, then you may read the file backwards with the [`file_read_backwards`](https://file-read-backwards.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)  library.

```
from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards(filename, encoding="utf-8") as frb:
    for line in frb:
        if word in line:
            # Do something
```

where `filename` contains the name of the file and `word` is the string you are looking for.