# How to do non-greedy regex on head

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here's a string for example

```
Clone into repo1...
some text
Clone into repo2...
some text
Clone into repo3...
some text
fatal: Some exception was thrown.
```

I'm trying to get the last "Clone into repo3" and the fatal message.
Here's the regex I'm writing:
`(Clone into.+fatal:.+?$)` with flags, `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE

But I got the whole message.
I know somehow we can do this `.*(Clone into.+fatal:.+?$)` but the text I'm dealing is really large, if `.*` is used at the front will cause a huge time cost.

Thank you all for your help!

**EDIT**

I'm looking for a regex way because I have almost ten regexes and I don't know which regex will be matched.

Here's the framework I wrote:

```py
# Here's almost 10 compiled regex, some of them have this duplicated issue.
regex_list = [...]

for regex in regex_list:
    res = regex.findall(log_text)
    if res:
        reason = res[0]
        break
```

If there's no way to handle this problem with regex, maybe I'll reconsider changing all these regexes into a common function to do `rsplit` first then.

BTW, the `rsplit` way needs the test stopped after the fatal error is thrown. If the test keeps running after a fatal error is raised, this method will not match the exception...

Comment: Probably you should not use a regex for this, check the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081898/find-the-last-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-large-file-with-python).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for your new option:) but if I only get the last line of `fatal` and the last line of `clone into`, maybe there will be another `fatal` between these lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a long text it might make sense to first split and then match what you need in the resulting substring. For example:

```
import re

text = """
    Clone into repo1...
    some text
    Clone into repo2...
    some text
    Clone into repo3...
    some text
    fatal: Some exception was thrown.
    """

# Get the part after the last 'Clone into '
end = text.rsplit("Clone into ", 1)[1]
# Capture clone and fatal messages.
match = re.search(r'\A(.*)\r?\n[\s\S]*?\b(fatal: .*)', end)
# Fetch captures, if there are any.
groups = None if match is None else match.groups()

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
('repo3...', 'fatal: Some exception was thrown.')
```

If you still need the phrase `Clone into`, simply prepend it when you use the first capturing group. The whole thing can possibly be done more elegantly with a substring, but the syntax escapes me.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question to make it clearer (and also my concerns). If no regex method can save me I'll turn to use this method after the whole text is caught by the original regex. In this way I can make sure what kind of text I should split with.

Comment: @HanxiFu I doubt that you can do this with one expression in the Python regex flavour, since it does not support atomic grouping or possessive quantifiers. You need those to tell the regex engine not to backtrack into already consumed areas when you have several quantified groups in the expression which the engine can try to juggle in order to obtain a match.